# Android: Search a specific nearby place type using maps api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am creating a Google Maps app. In my app I am searching for nearby ATM by using Places type "atm". It all works perfectly, but I have to find specific nearby ATM such as Axis bank ATM so please solve my problem using following code.......

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    String[] mPlaceType=null;
    String[] mPlaceTypeName=null;
    Spinner mSprPlaceType;
    double mLatitude=0;
    double mLongitude=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Array of place types
        mPlaceType = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type);

        // Array of place type names
        mPlaceTypeName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.place_type_name);

        // Creating an array adapter with an array of Place types
        // to populate the spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mPlaceTypeName);

        // Getting reference to the Spinner
        mSprPlaceType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spr_place_type);

        // Setting adapter on Spinner to set place types
        mSprPlaceType.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button btnFind;

        // Getting reference to Find Button
        btnFind = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_find);

        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        } else { // Google Play Services are available


            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                checkLocationPermission();
            }
            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

        // Setting click event lister for the find button
        btnFind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int selectedPosition = mSprPlaceType.getSelectedItemPosition();
                //String type = mPlaceType[selectedPosition];
                String type = "atm";
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
                sb.append("location="+mLatitude+","+mLongitude);
                sb.append("&radius=5000");
                sb.append("&types="+type);
                sb.append("&sensor=true");
                sb.append("&key=******************************");

                // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download json data
                PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();

                // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class PlaceTask
                placesTask.execute(sb.toString());

            }
        });
    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

        return data;
    }



    /** A class, to download Google Places */
    private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        String data = null;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try{
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Start parsing the Google places in JSON format
            // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParseTask
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>{



        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;

            List<HashMap<String, String>> places = new ArrayList<>();
            PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                /** Getting the parsed data as a List construct */
                places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String,String>> list){

            // Clears all the existing markers
            mMap.clear();

            for(int i=0;i < list.size();i++){

                // Creating a marker
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                // Getting a place from the places list
                HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);

                // Getting latitude of the place
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));

                // Getting longitude of the place
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

                // Getting name
                String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");

                // Getting vicinity
                String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");

                if(name.contains("axis")){

                }

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                // Setting the position for the marker
                markerOptions.position(latLng);

                // Setting the title for the marker.
                //This will be displayed on taping the marker
                markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);

                // Placing a marker on the touched position
                Marker m = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            }
        }
    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest,this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;


        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    ==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            }
        }
        else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResult){
        switch (requestCode){
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {

                if(grantResult.length > 0
                        && grantResult[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        if(mGoogleApiClient == null){
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permisison denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any response ?

Comment: No, you can see that their is no answer till yet.

Comment: check the answer below @Rishabh. See if this solves your issue

Comment: @Rishabh I asked did you got any response from server?

Comment: Oh you mean that way. I got all the  near by ATM from my current location and i am using API key for searching nearby ATM.@maveň

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to this by comparing the name of the place returned with the text you want (in this case axis). By that I mean, when you execute the above query, you are returned the name of the places; (here it would be name of all the banks ATMs). What you could do is to check if the returned names contains the word axis. The code below could be a good start point.

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
        if (list.size()>0){
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);
                final String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");
                String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");
                if (name.contains("axis")){
                   //do some awesome stuff here
                   LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                   // Setting the position for the marker
                   markerOptions.position(latLng);

                  // Setting the title for the marker.
                 //This will be displayed on taping the marker
                 markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);

                // Placing a marker on the touched position
                Marker m = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                }
            }
        }
    }// onPostExecute
}// end of the parserTask class
```

Comment: do you have a parserTask class? This is the onPostExecute method of that class.

Comment: i am confuse, please tell me what should i do after if condition brackets?

Comment: add the attributes you want in another list.

Comment: i am not getting you. can you please give me some example what should i do.

Comment: I think if you just copy the code below the `if(name.contains...)` into the if, it should work

Comment: and use `if (name.contains...)` instead of `if (!name.contains...)`. I made a typo in the code, edited now

Comment: I've updated my my answer; You did not placed the code below if inside if. I've done that. Check the edit (history)

Comment: is output still everything or null?

Comment: I do not have much experience with maps. You must be missing something please have a close look at the code.

Comment: @Rishabh It won't shown specific bank ATM ... all are shown .. you Can set the radius for limiting the area.

Comment: @Rishabh see finally you figured it out. If this answer helped, help others by accepting it.

Comment: yaa sure why not @7geeky

Comment: can you don one more favour ? If i want to show different atm like axis, idbi, etc through buttons can i do that?

Comment: declare a `String foo`. onClick of the button set this value to the name of the bank and in the if condition change `axis` to `foo`

Answer (score -1):

This is working absolutely fine for me:

```
sb.append("&name="+"\"axis+bank+atm\"");
```